# Why does this solution not work when trying to determiune if an array is a factor chain

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the question

A factor chain is an array where each previous element is a factor of the next consecutive element. The following is a factor chain:

```
[3, 6, 12, 36]

// 3 is a factor of 6
// 6 is a factor of 12
// 12 is a factor of 36
```

Create a function that determines whether or not an array is a factor chain.
Examples

```
factorChain([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]) ➞ true

factorChain([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) ➞ true

factorChain([2, 4, 6, 7, 12]) ➞ false

factorChain([10, 1]) ➞ false
```

I have no idea why this solution does not work, can someone please explain it to me.

```
function factorChain(arr) {
    return arr.slice(1).reverse().every((x, i)=> x % arr[i + 1] === 0);
}
```

But this way does work?

```
function factorChain(arr) {
    return arr.slice(1).every((num, i) => num % arr[i] === 0);
}
```

I know there are other ways to do it, but I want to know why this way does not work. And why does the other way work but not the first? In Array.every(num, i) the i returns the index of the current element, and num is the current element. so it looks like the function is trying to find the remainder between the current item and itself? that doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: `console.log(arr[i + 1])`

Comment: `reverse` only reverses the result of `arr.slice(1)`, not `arr`.

Comment: See my answer for explanation.
It also has two snippets!  :)
Either use `arr[arr.length - 2 - i]`,
Or `arr.slice().reverse()[i + 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You reversed the array in the function that does not work, such that the nth last element now has index n (with 0th last element being *the* last element using this terminology). However, you then compare the nth last element with the n+1th element of the original, unreversed array `arr` instead of the n+1th ***last*** element. This is why the first function does not work.

Comment: I do not understand all this terminology, can you please give an example? or put this in lamence terms?

Comment: All I'm saying is that let the 0th last element be the last element. If that's the case, then the nth last element in your original array becomes the element with index n when you reverse the array. Usually, when someone says nth last element, they mean the 1st last element to be the last element, the 2nd last element to the one before that, and so on, but this would not work in this case because the last element does not have index 1 when you reverse the array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you removed the "smallest" and then reversed, you need to modulo second-from-last:

```
function factorChain(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1).reverse().every((x, i)=> x % arr[arr.length-2-i] === 0);
}
```

```js
function factorChain(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1).reverse().every((x, i)=> x % arr[arr.length-2-i] === 0);
}

console.log(
  "factorChain([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]) ->\n  (expected: true) " +
  factorChain([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32])
);

console.log(
  "factorChain([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) ->\n  (expected: true)  " +
  factorChain([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
);

console.log(
  "factorChain([2, 4, 6, 7, 12]) ->\n  (expected: false)  " +
  factorChain([2, 4, 6, 7, 12])
);

console.log(
  "factorChain([10, 1]) ->\n  (expected: false)  " +
  factorChain([10, 1])
);
```

Another way of doing it is to modulo a reversed array.
But, since `reverse()` affects the original array, we can make a (shallow?) copy of the array using `slice()`.

Basically, insert `.slice().reverse()` between `x % arr` and `[i + 1] === 0`.

```
function factorChain(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1).reverse().every((x, i)=> x % arr.slice().reverse()[i + 1] === 0);
}
```

```js
function factorChain(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1).reverse().every((x, i)=> x % arr.slice().reverse()[i + 1] === 0);
}

console.log(
  "factorChain([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]) ->\n  (expected: true)  " +
  factorChain([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32])
);

console.log(
  "factorChain([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) ->\n  (expected: true)  " +
  factorChain([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
);

console.log(
  "factorChain([2, 4, 6, 7, 12]) ->\n  (expected: false)  " +
  factorChain([2, 4, 6, 7, 12])
);

console.log(
  "factorChain([10, 1]) ->\n  (expected: false)  " +
  factorChain([10, 1])
);
```